I'm getting a missing definition type 'androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle' when using Koin to inject a viewmodel. Is there a fix?
I am using Koin (ver 3.5.6) for my dependency injection on Android Jetpack Compose.  I have a viewmodel I use to view file items:
class FileViewModel(
    private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val fileRepository: IFileRepository,
) : ViewModel()

My app crashes with the error: org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for type 'androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandle'
I've set up my Koin module as so:
val ioModule = module {
    single { provideIoDispatcher() }

    factory<IFileRepository> { provideFileRepository(get()) }

    factoryOf(::GetFilesInDirectory)

    viewModelOf(::FileViewModel)

}

Documentation states this should "just work" but doesn't.  Any suggestions to resolve this issue?
I've swapped different dependencies:
# Koin
io-koin-bom = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-bom", version.ref = "koin-core" }
io-koin-core = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-core", version.ref = "koin-core" }

io-koin-core-coroutines = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-core-coroutines", version.ref = "koin-core" }

io-koin-android = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-android", version.ref = "koin-core" }
io-koin-androidx-compose = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-androidx-compose", version.ref = "koin-core" }

# Jetpack WorkManager
io-koin-androidx-workmanager = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-androidx-workmanager", version.ref = "koin-core" }

# Navigation Graph
io-koin-androidx-navigation = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-androidx-navigation", version.ref = "koin-core" }

io-koin-ksp-compiler = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-ksp-compiler", version.ref = "koin-compiler" }
io-koin-annotations = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-annotations", version.ref = "koin-compiler" }

io-koin-test = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-test", version.ref = "koin-core" }
io-koin-test-unit4 = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-test-junit4", version.ref = "koin-core" }
io-koin-test-unit5 = { group = "io.insert-koin", name = "koin-test-junit5", version.ref = "koin-core" }


No matter which combinations I use, I still get the same issue.
